# Wordpress WP_Query search parameter database issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've a problem with WP_Query, i notice that when i used the 's' parameter, every query returns empty.

After research on my Wordpress configuration, I've seen that the SQL request from my query failed.

The SQL request associated with my query :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dahu_wp_posts.ID 
FROM dahu_wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  
AND (((((dahu_wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%cantina%') 
OR (dahu_wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%cantina%'))) 
OR ((option_value LIKE '%cantina%')) ))  
AND (dahu_wp_posts.post_password = '')  
AND dahu_wp_posts.post_type = 'ait-item' 
AND (dahu_wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  
ORDER BY dahu_wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%cantina%' DESC, 
dahu_wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"
```

On an other site this request is quite the same excepted that their is a LEFT JOIN onto wp_options table.

Can someone know why this append ? And how can i fix it ?

Wordpress: 4.2.8
PHP: 5.3

Comment: What error ere you getting when the query fails? What is generating that Query? Its very difficult to work out whats going on with all the nested (and unnecessary) parentheses. Also is that final `"` supposed to be there?

Comment: The Sql request failed because option_value isn't recognised. This query is generated with a new WP_Query with "post_type" => "ait-item" and "s" => "cantina"

Comment: The final " isn't appropriate, doesn't appears in the request

Comment: Where is "option_value" getting added to the query? Its not prefixed with the table name so it will cause a problem. WP_Query will handle this correctly, so are you *sure* this is being generated directly by WP_Query, and that there isn't some filter changing it? Can you also include the WP_Query code so we can see it?

Comment: I don't know where, and i don't know why. How can i be sure that it's not modified by a filter ? I've one theme and some plugins but when i desactive all the plugin the bug still exists.

Comment: $data = new WP_query(array('post_type' => 'ait-item', 's'=>'cantina')); My query !

Comment: There are a number of different hooks that can change the SQL query, such as: `pre_get_posts`, the `query_posts`, `wp_the_query ` and a number of SQL filters too. As you've ruled out plugins, try a default WP theme to see if that makes a difference. What version of WP are you on? I ran your query on my WP4.8.2 and it looks quite different.

Comment: I'm on Wordpress 4.5.2 too, i've tried to change my theme and it works perfectly, so now i'm searching for a filter in my theme code !

Comment: Well at least you know where to start looking now! Your functions.php is the most likely place for these kind of filters, but they could be anywhere.